# AJAX with jQuery not returning data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#like').bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var likeMsg = $('#like').val();
            if(likeMsg) {
                // Send the AJAX request to like.php
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'like.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('Content: ' + data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my `like.php` file:

```
<?php

echo "It works! :)";

?>
```

When I press enter on the `#like` input, it seems the AJAX request is sent and an alert box comes up saying: `Content:`, but there's no data being sent back from `like.php`...

I have checked if the file exists and if it's in the same directory and whatever and it is, so I'm pretty much clueless atm.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys. In my markup I had:

```
<form action="">
    <p><input type="text" id="like" class="like" /></p>
</form>
```

So the page was refreshing when I was pressing enter in the text box which is what I look for in my Javascript code. I removed the `<form>` elements and all works now.

Silly mistake, should of noticed it sooner. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be fine but [debugging the ajax request](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/debugging-ajax-requests/) might lead to a better position.

Comment: According to Firebug the AJAX request is never actually sent. At least, it's not showing up so there's nothing to debug really.

Comment: @James P: Then you have to debug your code, possible there is some javascript error, check with firebug or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If no `dataType` is provided, it tries to choose among: "xml, json, script, or html".

Try adding `dataType` with the value "text":

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'like.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
        alert('Content: ' + data);
      })
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work with the text data type. Probably a good idea to keep that in there though so thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

Actually, looks like all you want is to pipe the out put of a file somewhere. Check out $.load or $.get, both are more inline with what you are looking for I think.

Comment: I would really want to send some data to like.php though, so I don't think load or get would fit my needs very well?